# Django seems to be falsely claiming an SQL syntax error

Tags: sql, django, sqlite, django-models

Django seems to be falsely claiming that I have an error in my SQL syntax.  The query runs fine (returning the intended results) in the django dbshell but spawns an error when the query is run through Django.  Here is the code (tracebacks follow):

```
#this code is inside the models.Customer.display_sharers() function
sharers_by_action_count = Sharer.objects.raw('''
SELECT wordout_sharer.id, COUNT(actions_of_type.id) AS action_count
FROM
wordout_customer
INNER JOIN wordout_sharer
 ON wordout_sharer.customer_id = wordout_customer.id
LEFT JOIN wordout_click
 ON wordout_sharer.id = wordout_click.sharer_id
LEFT JOIN
(SELECT wordout_action.id, wordout_action.click_id
FROM wordout_action
WHERE
wordout_action.action_type_id = %s) as actions_of_type
 ON actions_of_type.click_id = wordout_click.id
WHERE wordout_customer.id = %s
GROUP BY wordout_sharer.id
ORDER BY action_count %s
''', (action_type_id, self.id, direction))

force_execution = list(sharers_by_action_count) #force the query to run by converting it to a list.. this is to trigger the error.
```

Here is the traceback:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<console>", line 1, in <module>
  File "/Users/me/sources/django_wordout/../django_wordout/wordout/models.py", line 106, in display_sharers
    if order_by == 'action_count': #we have to make a special query for when they want to sort by the count of a specific action
  File "/Users/me/sources/django_wordout/../django_wordout/wordout/models.py", line 92, in sharers_by_action_count_with_total_clicks
    force_exec = list(sharers_by_action_count)
  File "/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/django/db/models/query.py", line 1324, in __iter__
    query = iter(self.query)
  File "/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/django/db/models/sql/query.py", line 67, in __iter__
    self._execute_query()
  File "/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/django/db/models/sql/query.py", line 81, in _execute_query
    self.cursor.execute(self.sql, self.params)
  File "/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/django/db/backends/util.py", line 34, in execute
    return self.cursor.execute(sql, params)
  File "/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/django/db/backends/sqlite3/base.py", line 234, in execute
    return Database.Cursor.execute(self, query, params)
DatabaseError: near "?": syntax error
```

When `Database.Cursor.execute(self, query, params)` is executed, here are the values of all the parameters:

**self**:

```
<django.db.backends.sqlite3.base.SQLiteCursorWrapper object at 0x10c477180>
```

**query**:

```
        SELECT wordout_sharer.id, COUNT(actions_of_type.id) AS action_count
        FROM
        wordout_customer
        INNER JOIN wordout_sharer
         ON wordout_sharer.customer_id = wordout_customer.id
        LEFT JOIN wordout_click
         ON wordout_sharer.id = wordout_click.sharer_id
        LEFT JOIN
        (SELECT wordout_action.id, wordout_action.click_id
        FROM wordout_action
        WHERE
        wordout_action.action_type_id = ?) as actions_of_type
         ON actions_of_type.click_id = wordout_click.id
        WHERE wordout_customer.id = ?
        GROUP BY wordout_sharer.id
        ORDER BY action_count ?
```

**params:**

```
         (1, 1, 'DESC')
```

Have I found a bug in Django?  Is it not possible for it to deal with certain types of queries correctly?

**My configuration**: I am running a pretty vanilla development configuration.  For the db engine, I'm using sqlite.  For migrations (which are up to date), I'm using South.

### Update

Just found that replacing the `%s`'s with their values makes the query work..  What could be going on to make the `%s`'s problematic for Django?

Comment: Are you sure you're not sending the query with an extra set of single quotes around the whole question? It looks like that from the dump.

Comment: My code exactly matches what I pasted in the code snippet

Comment: Ah, but just found something really interesting -- the query runs fine when I don't use `%s` and send the values directly.  What could be the issue?

Comment: I know you can't parameterize sort order on some databases but I'm not sure about Sqlite, try changing just that parameter.

Comment: Yep, the order parameterizing order was the issue.  If you could post an answer with a link to relevant docs (if they exist) I'd gratefully mark it as correct

Comment: Added an answer with a bit more of an explanation why sqlite behaves like this.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

[According to this page](http://www.sqlite.org/c3ref/bind_blob.html), sqlite treats parameterized values as literals, which means that they insert constants of the type given instead of doing regular "text replacement".

Since ASC or DESC in an order by is a keyword, not a constant, it can't be replaced by a parameter.

This actually gives some possibly unexpected behavior, if you for example do

```
ORDER BY ? DESC
```

and you give it a column name (say column1), it actually runs but doesn't sort in your expected order. The reason being that it actually sorts by the string "column1" - which is the same for every row - instead of the actual column content.

Answer (score 0):

I found myself in a similar situation. In both of our cases, we're doing things the right way by NOT using string formatting:

```
Database.Cursor.execute(self, query, params)
```

However, if you absolutely trust your inputs (i.e. they are system-supplied, not user-provided) I found I could bypass this error by doing things the dangerous way:

```
Database.Cursor.execute(self, query % tuple(params))
```

To future readers: just be advised this makes you vulnerable to SQL injection if you use this as a workaround. If you don't understand what this means, don't do it!